# Damaged heap while working with dynamically allocated variables and _chdir windows function

Tags: c++, c, windows, dynamic, char

while working with those function i'm getting stuck with an error.
The debbuger says "damged heap" on `_chdir(dirCorrente);` line.

The main calls those function as follow:
 - char* temp = getCartellaCorrente();
 - some other stuff not relative to these function...
 - temp = setCartellaCorrente("cd test")

when the execution stops the setCartellaCorrente's dirCorrente value is '"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\remote-control-project\FirstService\Debug\test"'

I think i'm doing something wrong with dynamically allocated variables.

I'm working on this problem since 48 hours now, i've serached on the internet but nothing. I guess that i don't know something important about allocated variable or _chdir function.

I will be really gratefull if you can explain me what i miss.

```
char* getCartellaCorrente() {
    char* temp;
    size_t size;
    LPWSTR dirCorrente = new TCHAR[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    GetCurrentDirectory(DEFAULT_BUFLEN, dirCorrente);
    size = wcslen(dirCorrente);
    temp = (char *)malloc(size);
    wcstombs_s(NULL, temp, size+1, dirCorrente, size);
    return temp;
}

char* setCartellaCorrente(char* relative) {
    char *dirCorrente;

    if (strlen(relative)>=5 && relative[4] == ':') {
        dirCorrente = (char *)malloc(DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
        strcpy_s(dirCorrente, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, &relative[3]);
    }
    else {
        dirCorrente = getCartellaCorrente();
        relative[2] = '\\';
        strcat_s(dirCorrente, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, &relative[2]);
        printf("goode %s \n", dirCorrente);
    }
    //fixPathSlash(dirCorrente);
    printf("\n2: %s\n", dirCorrente);
    int i = _chdir(dirCorrente); //HERE IT STOPS
    printf("wtf: %d\n", i);
    free(dirCorrente);
    printf("boh\n");
    return getCartellaCorrente();
}
```

It's my first question. Sorry if i missed some important information, i'll edit fast.

Comment: The `_chdir`didn't damage your path, you're overwriting a buffer somewhere. Also you absolutely **must** provide a [mcve], a short example that reproduces the problem, including the `main` function and the *included* headers.

Comment: This code doesn't compile because `/fixPathSlash`

Comment: Also your code is **C++**, not C, because a) you're compiling with C++ compiler, b) you're using `new`.

Comment: And since your code is C++ you need to write C++ code, instead of spaghetti C. Proper, modern C++ code does not use `malloc`, `free`, and other error-prone functions inherited from C. Proper, modern C++ code uses containers that handle their own memory management, greatly reducing the opportunity for corrupting the heap as a result of mistakes in manually managing memory allocations. You need to rewrite your code in modern C++.

Comment: You allocate `size` bytes with `malloc(size)` and then write to `size+1` bytes with `wcstomb_s`. There is also a bug with your calculation of the size of the temp buffer. There are cases where the size of the `char` buffer is more than half the size of the corresponding `wchar_t` buffer. (Later you try to `strcat_s` into that buffer, which is another corruption.) I think you have some more basic misunderstanding of how dynamic memory works. Maybe practice with something simpler first.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala single slash on comment was just i missclick

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i don't know what you mean for spaghetti C, what i wrote is just simple C, since i don't know nothing of c++, i've studied Java, but i wanted to use some of windows lib.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes i know i did some stupid things XD size+1 in wcstomb was an error i made will testing for a solution.

Comment: Anyway for now i've resolved not using allocated variable. one day when i will need it, i'll study better and i'll fix

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to solve the problem, as i thoght the problem was the allocation.
Since i need to solve this fast for now i've used the method i listed above, anyway i will study how to work with allocated variable and modify it to improve it.

```
void getCartellaCorrente(char* temp) {
    size_t size;
    LPWSTR dirCorrente = new TCHAR[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    GetCurrentDirectory(DEFAULT_BUFLEN, dirCorrente);
    size = wcslen(dirCorrente);
    wcstombs_s(NULL, temp, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, dirCorrente, size);
}

void setCartellaCorrente(char* relative, char* dirCorrente) {

    if (strlen(relative)>=5 && relative[4] == ':') {
        strcpy_s(dirCorrente, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, &relative[3]);
    }
    else {
        getCartellaCorrente(dirCorrente);
        relative[2] = '\\';
        strcat_s(dirCorrente, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, &relative[2]);
    }
    int i = _chdir(dirCorrente);
    return getCartellaCorrente(dirCorrente);
}
```

The path variable is now allocated into the main with static size, the functions does not return the correct value, instead they change it directly.

Comment: You are still doing it wrong.  Never, *never* lie, you have no idea that temp has DEFAULT_BUFLEN elements.  Lies produce corrupted heaps.  If you don't want to allocate it (correctly, like Raymond said) so you can accept any string then at least pass the buffer length as an argument.

Comment: @HansPassant i actually have initialize it as "char temp[DEFAULT_BUFLEN]. It's just a quick fix to make things till i learn how to properly allocate at run time. What do you mean saying "never lie"?